# C program to check lottery numbers: why some tests fail?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, vector

This program takes as an input the following lines:

```
23 12 33 19 10 8
5
23 19 8 12 60 18
14 60 12 44 54 10
8 3 12 19 33 10
33 15 7 60 12 10
22 12 19 23 33 11
```

23 12 33 19 10 8 ( The first line ) are the lottery results.
n ( in this specific case, 5 ) informs how many lines will follow below.

Each line has 6 numbers. The number order doesn't matter.

The rules are: numbers range from 1 to 60 ( including 1 and 60 ) and they never repeat themselves in the same line.

The variable "quadra" stores how many lines have got 4 numbers right.

The variable "quina" stores how many lines have got 5 numbers right.

The variable "sena" stores how many lines have got 6 numbers right.

So, a computer program is running some tests over my code below and it's claiming that it goes wrong for most of them, but I can't see what's the problem here. Does anybody have a clue? Is this code wrong, or is there something wrong with the software that's testing this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int mega[6];
    int v[50500][6];
    int n,swap; 
    int i,j,k; //counters
    int quadra,quina,sena;
    quadra = 0;
    quina = 0;
    sena = 0;
    for(i=0;i<6;++i) scanf("%i",&mega[i]); //first line, lottery results
    scanf("%i",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        for(j=0;j<6;++j){
            scanf("%i",&v[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        for(j=0;j<6;++j){
            for(k=0;k<6;++k){
                if(v[i][j] == mega[k]){
                    v[i][j] = 61;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //reverse bubble sort
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        for(j=0;j<6;++j){
            for(k=j+1;k<6;++k){
                if(v[i][j] < v[i][k]){
                    swap = v[i][k];
                    v[i][k] = v[i][j];
                    v[i][j] = swap;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        for(j=0;v[i][j] == 61 && j<6;++j);
        if(j == 4) ++quadra;
        else if(j == 5) ++quina;
        else if(j == 6) ++sena;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program produces no output. Perhaps that's wrong?

Comment: Stack overflow, and loop is not right.

Comment: Unrelated, a *flag array* of size 60 containing lit values only for numbers in the winning line will eliminate the triple nest and increase your efficiency considerably. Just saying.

Comment: It's not meant to print the variables, but they should store the correct values.

Comment: @Ruan If some other program is going to test it, you're going to have to output their values so it can check them. How are you testing it yourself? In a debugger?

Comment: You're spending far more time sorting than you're saving from it in that final loop, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a couple of noteworthy issues with your code:

Compile time indicates possibility of uninitialized variable:

[image]

But, ***run-time*** results in fatal run-time at unknown source location. *Stack overflow*.  It is likely due to this line:

```
int v[50500][6];
```

Increase your stack size.  It needs to be about 2.5Mbytes for `v` alone.

Also, this line may not be what you intended:

```
for(i=0;i<6;++i) scanf("%i",&mega[i]); //first line, lottery results
                                     ^
```

If you meant to loop around the remainder of the code, remove the `;` after the `for()` statement, and use curly braces:

```
for(i=0;i<6;++i) scanf("%i",&mega[i]) //first line, lottery results
{
    scanf("%i",&n);
    ....
```

Comment: I didn't mean it to loop through the entire code. It's just meant to receive the first line ( lottery results ) as input.

Comment: Okay.  I was not sure.  Then ignore the comments about curly braces in that case.  But definitely increase your stack size to accommodate the large array variable. :)  Also, although I do not think your code is running into uninitialized variables, it is still a good habit to explicitly initialize them before use.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is true, I understood and tried the flow of it. Looks fine but if you dont need to sort everyline (and use j as a counter in this loop `for(j=0;v[i][j] == 61 && j<6;++j);` ), you can use simpler `if`statements to compare real lottery results with the ones that entered. What I mean is that your algorithm is a little complex. Try a simple one and see how it works.

Comment: I tried something really stupid ( if statements ) and it worked perfectly. So yes, I was just overcomplicating things.